# <router-outlet> works fine but causes problems <page-router-outlet>

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]

I am creating NativeScript - Angular app. I had a problem with routing inside my app with not working back button (back button in my smartphone, it is supposed to go back to previous page but it is turning off my app).

I was using  in my app.component.html file so I changed it to  and back buttons started to works like it supposed to but layout of my home page is completly destroyed - all objects in in overlap on themselfs and "Preview" ActionBar appears in one of .

```
<!-- app.component.html -->

<GridLayout class="page">
    <ScrollView>
    <GridLayout rows="80 *" columns="*">
        <FlexboxLayout class="menu">      
<Image class="menu" src="~/app/images/burger.png" width="10%"></Image>
          </FlexboxLayout>
          <ScrollView></ScrollView>
            <GridLayout class="bialy" row="1" rows="*" columns="*">
              <FlexboxLayout>
                  <GridLayout class="space"></GridLayout>
                  <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
                </FlexboxLayout>
            </GridLayout>
          </GridLayout> 
        </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>

<!-- app.css -->

GridLayout.page {
    background: linear-gradient(-85deg, #08BD73, #02A373);
    flex-direction: column;
}
GridLayout.bialy {
    background: white;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 40 40 0 0;
    justify-content: center;
}

<!-- home.component.html -->
<Button text="Add" [nsRouterLink]="['/new']"></Button>
<Button text="Watering" [nsRouterLink]="['/watering']"></Button>
<Button text="catalog" [nsRouterLink]="['/catalog']" ></Button>
```

What shall I do to make my app with  the same as app version with

This is how version with  looks like (screen 1):
And this is how version with  looks like (and I want my app to look like this) (screen 2)

Comment: Back button was turning off your app? It sounds more like a crash. Can you show some screenshots, of what you are expecting and what you are seeing?

Comment: I have edited my post and added screen shots. I guess it is not crashing, when I tap back button app is closing to phone main screen and it is open in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `actionBarVisibility` to `never` on `page-router-outlet` to hide the action bar.

Your home component doesn't seem to have any layout which may be the reason you are seeing only the last button, wrap them with a `StackLayout`.